# Azure Policy Not Denying Route Creation

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I want to make an Azure policy that denies anyone trying to create a route to certain prefixes that don't use the next hop virtual appliance parameter and IP that I specify. I have this working with just a single prefix (0.0.0.0/0 internet route) but as soon as I try to define other routes (10.0.0.0/8) it doesn't work. Here is what I have so far:

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "field": "type",
                            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*]",
                                "where": {
                                    "anyOf": [
                                        {
                                            "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].addressPrefix",
                                            "equals": "0.0.0.0/0"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "anyOf": [
                                                {
                                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].nextHopType",
                                                    "notEquals": "VirtualAppliance"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].nextHopIpAddress",
                                                    "notEquals": "[parameters('routeTableSettings')[field('location')].virtualApplianceIpAddress]"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].addressPrefix",
                                            "equals": "10.0.0.0/8"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "anyOf": [
                                                {
                                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].nextHopType",
                                                    "notEquals": "VirtualAppliance"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].nextHopIpAddress",
                                                    "notEquals": "[parameters('routeTableSettings')[field('location')].virtualApplianceIpAddress]"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "greater": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "field": "type",
                            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes"
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].addressPrefix",
                            "equals": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        },
                        {
                            "anyOf": [
                                {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes/nextHopType",
                                    "notEquals": "VirtualAppliance"
                                },
                                {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes/nextHopIpAddress",
                                    "notEquals": "[parameters('routeTableSettings')[field('location')].virtualApplianceIpAddress]"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "type",
                            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes"
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].addressPrefix",
                            "equals": "10.0.0.0/8"
                        },
                        {
                            "anyOf": [
                                {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes/nextHopType",
                                    "notEquals": "VirtualAppliance"
                                },
                                {
                                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes/nextHopIpAddress",
                                    "notEquals": "[parameters('routeTableSettings')[field('location')].virtualApplianceIpAddress]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "routeTableSettings": {
            "type": "Object",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "Route Table Settings",
                "description": "Location-specific settings for route tables."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parameters

```
{
    "eastus2": {
        "virtualApplianceIpAddress": "10.1.1.1"
    },
    "disabled": {
        "virtualApplianceIpAddress": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: with too many `anyOf`, it's extremely difficult to have a look. Also, `Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes` has been duplicated. Not the exact cause but just found it. 

There is an `in` clause which you can use within `policyRule`. It's better you keep on adding the route CIDRs to that list rather repeating this. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement ***we need to use `IN` clause in our azure policy to deny/not allow the resource type to create .***

As suggested by @[***harshavmb***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405980/harshavmb) in comment which is correct. Posting it as an answer to help other community members to find fix their issue for the same.
The [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure) has an example how to use the `in` with policy rule:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Allowed locations",
        "description": "This policy enables you to restrict the locations your organization can specify when deploying resources.",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "Locations"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "allowedLocations": {
                "type": "array",
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources",
                    "strongType": "location",
                    "displayName": "Allowed locations"
                },
                "defaultValue": [ "westus2" ]
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "not": {
                    "field": "location",
                    "in": "[parameters('allowedLocations')]"
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also from Azure portal>Policy> Not allowed resource we can find the `json` with `in` clause .
As shown below:
[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Not_allowed_resource_types***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/policy-reference#general)

***BLOG:-*** [***AZURE POLICY TO DENY CREATION OF ALL RESOURCES***](https://darawtechie.com/2021/02/02/azure-policy-to-deny-creation-of-all-resources/)